# I keep getting JSONFilterProvider <- JSONFilter Unpr Angular error and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer-8

Here's my code for what I'm doing:

```
<!-- underscore -->
    <script src="js/underscore.js/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="js/angular/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/controllers/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/directives/directives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/services/data-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The code above is located at the bottom.

This is the error I'm getting in the Google

Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: JSONFilterProvider <- JSONFilter
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$injector/unpr?p0=JSONFilterProvider%20%3C-%20JSONFilter
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:68:12)
    at http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:4264:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:4411:39)
    at http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:4269:45
    at Object.getService [as get] (http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:4411:39)
    at $get (http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:18091:24)
    at isStateless (http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:12956:12)
    at findConstantAndWatchExpressions (http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:13013:33)
    at http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:12967:7
    at forEach (http://localhost/website/js/angular/angular.js:336:20)

I'm using angular-ui-router.js vice ng-Route.

The problem is, NOWHERE in the code am I referencing JSONFilter...

The error appears here in angular.js on line: 12321

```
// The reason behind this is that console.log has type "object" in IE8...
  try {
    hasApply = !!logFn.apply;
  } catch (e) {}

  if (hasApply) {
    return function() {
      var args = [];
      forEach(arguments, function(arg) {
        args.push(formatError(arg));
      });
      return logFn.apply(console, args);
    };
  }
```

I'm not using IE8 and never use internet Exploder or now, edge which immediately let in viruses. I dumped it on WINDOWS 10.

Back on point. Any clue where this is coming from or how I'm getting it?

BTW here's my app.js file:

```
/* global angular */

// Code goes here
var myApp;
myApp = angular.module("myApp", [
    "ui.router"

]);


myApp.config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {

    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['self', '**']);


});
myApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("home");

    $stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: "/home",
                views: {
                    "mainHeader": {
                      templateUrl: "templates/mainHeader.html"  

                    },
                    "mainNav": {
                      templateUrl: "templates/mainNav.html"  

                    },
                    "mainContent": {
                        templateUrl: "templates/home.html"

                    },
                    "mainFooter": {
                        templateUrl: "templates/mainFooter.html"

                    },
                    "homeDetails": {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/home-details.html'

                    }

                }

            })
            .state('about', {
                url: "about",
                views: {
                    "mainAbout": {
                        templateUrl: "templates/about.html"
                    },
                    "aboutDetails": {
                        templateUrl: 'templates/about-details.html'

                    }
                }

            });
});

console.log("Host name is: " + document.location.hostname);

if (document.location.hostname === "localhost") {
    myApp.constant('URL', '/website/js/json/');
} else if (document.location.hostname === "website.net" || "www.website.net") {
    myApp.constant('URL', '/js/json/');
} else {
    myApp.constant('URL', '/website/js/json/');
}


//Registering the company for the key achievements
//This defines and initializes a value service called company and assigns it an 
//object with some default values.

myApp.constant("nbrCompanies", {
    nbr: 0
});
myApp.constant("nbrSites", {
    nbr: 0
});
myApp.constant("nbrSkills", {
    nbr: 0
});
```

Thanks for your help...

UPDATE: Here's the  that contains the ui-views

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="homeController as ctrlHome">
        <!-- Nav UI View -->
        <nav id="mainbar" class="hidden-xs" ui-view="mainNav"></nav>
        <!-- Nav UI View -->
        <div id="wrap">
            <!-- injected header content -->
            <div id="header" ui-view="mainHeader"></div>
            <!-- injected main content -->
            <div id="bodyStuff" ui-view="mainContent"></div>
            <!-- End of Injected Content-->
            <!-- Detail View -->
            <div class="details" ui-view="homeDetails"></div>
            <!-- End Detail View -->  
        </div> <!-- wrap -->
        <footer id="footer" ui-view="mainFooter"></footer>
    </div> <!-- container -->
    <!-- underscore -->
    <script src="js/underscore.js/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular -->
    <script src="js/angular/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/controllers/controllers.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/directives/directives.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/angular/services/data-service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you perhaps referencing jsonfilter in your html? Or are you saying if you search your entire project jsonfilter doesn't come up at all?

Comment: Jeff, thanks for responding. Yes, JSONFilter comes up nowhere in any of the code. It only happens while I'm going through the code in debug mode and I come to populating the ui-view for the body.  It hits that section of angular.js and hasApply is null.  In the beginning, hasApply instantiates to info, warn, debug, error, log as indicated starting at line: 12246 in angular.js ver. 1.4.2.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:

Here in my call in my home.html page I have this code:

```
<div class="feature-widget">
            <article class="home-features-item hover">
                <div class="item-icon">
                    <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="item-content">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum mollit sunt</h3>
                    <!-- This is where the culprit was... SHOW is what was NEEDED -->
                    **<a ui-sref="detail({id: show.id})">{{show.name}}</a>**
                    <!-- This is what I had:... the word SHOWS was wrong
                    **<a ui-sref="detail({id: show.id})">{{shows.name}}</a>**
                    -->
                    <pre hidden="hidden">{{show|json}}</pre>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum Labore adipisicing nisi magna do nisi pariatur aliquip eu sed voluptate consequat sunt aute aliqua exercitation minim cupidatat.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum Ut dolor et anim occaecat ex aliquip esse labore fugiat in do magna dolore pariatur eiusmod irure officia.</p>
                </div>
            </article> <!-- home-features-item -->
        </div> <!-- feature-widget -->
```

and here's the controller and service where I was screwing up:

CONTROLLERS:

```
/* global myApp, ctrlRes */

'use strict';

myApp.controller('homeController',
    ['$scope','$state','homeDataService',
        function ($scope, $state, homeDataService) {
            var ctrlHome = this;

            ctrlHome.content = [];

            ctrlHome.fetchHome = function () {
                //General Data
                homeDataService.getHomeData().then(function (result) {
                    ctrlHome.content = result.data;
                    console.log("General: ", result.data);
                });
            };
            ctrlHome.fetchHome();

            //Redirects to a page sent into this function
            $scope.redirectToPage = function (pageToGoTo) {
                //if pageToGoTo = home, then route to /home!
                $state.go(pageToGoTo);
            };

            //Now we route with lists
            $scope.home = homeDataService.list();

}]);
//This is the details for HOME
myApp.controller('homeDetailController', 
    ['$scope','$stateParams', 'homeDataService', 
        function($scope, $stateParams, homeDataService) {

            var ctrlHmDets = this;
            ctrlHmDets.content = [];

            ctrlHmDets.content = homeDataService.find($stateParams.id);
            $scope.selectedShow = homeDataService.find($stateParams.id);


 }]);
```

SERVICE:

```
/* global myApp, _ */
var shows = [];

myApp.factory('homeDataService', function ($http, URL) {
    var getHomeData = function () {
        return $http.get(URL + 'general-junk.json')
                .success(function (data) {
                    console.log("SUCCESS!");
                    console.log("The General Junk Home: " + data.basedata.companyinfo);
                    return data.basedata.companyinfo;
                })
                .error(function (e) {
                    console.log("He\'s dead Jim!", e);
                    return e;
                });

    };

    //Details for the Home Page
    shows = [{
        id: 1,
        page: 'Home',
        name: 'Home Details',
        description: 'This is the detail content'
    }];
    return {
        getHomeData: getHomeData,
        list: function () {

            return shows;

        }, //This is for DETAILs if we should have them
        find: function (id) {
            return _.find(shows, function (show) {
                return show.id === id;
            });
        }
    };



});
```

Thanks, Jeff for the inspiration so DEBUG!